Getting This page is not available in lightning experience or mobile app for aura component url addressable
We installed our managed package to a client. We wanted to access one component which has three lightning components to work:

One LWC quick action to redirect to the main LWC
One Aura component url Adrressable that wraps the main LWC
Main LWC

The quick action LWC has this code:
@api recordId;

@api invoke(){
    getCuentaId({recordId: this.recordId}).then(id =>{
        console.log('cuenta id =======> ' + id);
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__auraConsultaSaldos'
            },
            state: {
                c__ctaId: id
            }
        }).then(url => window.open(url));
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

The aura wrapper:
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.reInit}"/>
    <c:consultaSaldos ctaId="{!v.pageReference.state.c__ctaId}"/>
</aura:component>

The main LWC has lots of code so there's not point in putting it here, but the main point is in our developer org where our package is, it works fine, but on the client's org when redirecting to the aura component the error message appears: "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app."
What am I missing? I believe no configuration is required for this to work. I don't remember that being a problem before.
Any ideas of what it could be?
EDIT: when it redirects, the url is /lightning/cmp/c__auraConsultaSaldos?c__ctaId=001Hs00002v0Q38IAE
if I change the prefix of the aura to the namespace of my package, it works... I believed the c__ was supposed to work in any org. What do I have to change in my code? Do I have to add the package's prefix directly instead of c__?
